# Como funciona csrf-protection no CodeIgniter?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, mvc, token, csrf

Hoje enquanto trabalhava num projeto em codeigniter, deparei-me com o conceito [CSRF - Cross-site request forgery](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). Isto aconteceu quando obtive o erro 403 - permission denided ao fazer um GET request em AJAX da VIEW para o MODEL.

Após investigar o assunto, surgiram algumas dúvidas.

1. O csrf protection é usada apenas para requests em formulários?
2. Como funciona para requests sem submissão de formulários?
3. Em que parte do request fica alojado o token do hash-protection?

Ainda é novo para mim... Mas pelo que percebi, o codeigniter gera através de uma função de hash, um token que impede que o site do invasor possa colocar o token direto nas suas alegações, este token é acessível em

```
$this->security->get_csrf_hash();
```

Agora, segundo a minha leitura, teremos de usar o token no request, para que possa ser comparado pelo token do codeigniter. Como enviamos o token no request?

**[Meu Código]**

**[view]**

```
// este request é feito quando desperto um evento choicelist.onchange()
$.ajax({
    url: CFG.url + "/application/models/Agenda_model/getAgendaDate",
    type: "get", //send it through get method
    data: { 
        date: '02-02-2019'
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        //Do Something to handle error
    }
});
// in footer.php, gera o primeiro token
var CFG = {
    url: '<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url');?>',
    token: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>'
};
// after request, guarda token sucessores
$(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajaxSetup({data: {token: CFG.token}});
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e,x) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(x.responseText);
        $.ajaxSetup({data: {token: result.token}});
    });
});
```

**[Model]**

```
public function getAgendaDate(){
        $sql = 'select * from agenda';
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        $send = array('token' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()) + $result;

        if (!headers_sent()) {
            header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
            header('Expires: ' . date('r'));
            header('Content-type: application/json');
        }
        // envia o novo token
        exit(json_encode($send, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
}
```

Acredito que o meu código, tenha uma pequena falha. No entanto estou receptível a novas abordagem, uma nova design pattern. Como resolvo o erro 403?

**[config.php]**

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'token';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

**[update] - 06-03-2019**

> Mudei o ajax request da VIEW para o Controller. Obtive o mesmo
>   erro:GET
>   http://localhost/calendar/application/controllers/BaseController/getAgendaDate?date=02-02-2019
>   403 (Forbidden)
>   De seguida fiz outra alteração com base [nesta documentação sobre
>   URLs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html). Alterei o url para
>   [http://localhost/nome_projeto/nome_controller/método](http://localhost/nome_projeto/nome_controller/m%C3%A9todo) Obtive o erro GET
>   http://localhost/calendar/basecontroller/getagendadate?date=02-02-2019&token=c058ce37a1246f496be4e8d1937b61b5
>   404 (Not Found)

**[Estrutura diretórios]**

```
calendar -
         - application
                       - cache
                       - config
                       - controllers
                                     - BaseController.php
                       - core
                       - helpers
                       - hooks
                       - language
                       - libraries
                       - logs
                       - models
                                - Agenda_model.php
                       - third_party
                       - views
                               - home.php
                       - .htaccess
                       - index
         - assets
         - system
         - .editorconfig
         - .gitignore
         - composer
         - contributing.md
         - index.php
```

**[config.php]**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/calendar';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'token';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

Comment: Cara, só um adendo. A _View_ não deve se comunicar diretamente com a camada _Model_. Em arquitetura _MVC_ o correto é utilizar um intermediário para isso, ou seja, o _Controller_.

Comment: Se reparar bem você está expondo a estrutura do _framework_ e também o seu _Model_: `/application/models/Agenda_model/getAgendaDate`.

Comment: @PauloImon obrigado pela dica. Tenho observado isso, vim do java, e em java a view recebe o model.

Comment: Sim, vou usar no Controller. Será que resolve o erro 403?

Comment: Certo. Creio que esse seja o motivo do 403 sim.

Comment: @PauloImon só mais uma pergunta. O método mais indicado para aceder ao model carregado no controller é usando um request em javascript da view para o controller? Ou existe outra alternativa?

Comment: Da _View_ para o _Controller_ não teria problema nenhum utilizar uma requisição _AJAX_. O _CodeIgniter_ mapeia o acesso aos recursos através de [segmentos](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=url#uri-segments), ou seja, seria o equivalente a digitar a _URL_ na barra de endereços do navegador.

Comment: No _CI_ você não deve utilizar a _URL_ diretamente dessa forma: `http://localhost/myTasks/application/controllers/BaseController/getAgendaDate?date=02-02-2019`. Todo o acesso via _URL_ é redirecionado para o arquivo `index.php` na raiz da aplicação. A estrutura das _URLs_ são assim: `example.com/class/function/ID`, ou seja, ficaria mais ou menos assim no seu caso: `http://localhost/myTasks/basecontroller/getagendadate?date=02-02-2019`.

Comment: Eu tentei, tive error 404 page not found. O meu base url é 'http://localhost:80/myTasks/application/controllers'

Comment: @PauloImon print_r($this->uri->segment_array()); retorna Array(). Tem alguma coisa haver?

Comment: Tente trocar a sua `$config['base_url']` para `http://localhost/mytasks`.

Comment: Obtive o erro, jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost/mytasks/basecontroller/getagendadate?date=02-02-2019 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @@PedroCorreia atualiza sua pergunta, mostra como está a estrutura de diretórios e os nomes dos _Controllers_.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90677/discussion-between-pedro-correia-and-paulo-imon).

Answer (score 1):

**1. O csrf protection é usada apenas para requests em formulários?**

Não. A própria [documentação](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/security.html?highlight=csrf#csrf-protection) diz que ele serve para toda requisição que não é um GET-HTTP:

> CodeIgniter provides CSRF protection out of the box, which will get
>   automatically triggered for every non-GET HTTP request, but also needs
>   you to create your submit forms in a certain way. This is explained in
>   the Security Library documentation.

Basicamente: afeta todas as requisições `$POST`, e também é aplicável aos `FORMS` que usarem `$POST`.

Quando você ativa o uso do *Cross-site request forgery (CSRF)* na configuração do `CodeIgniter` ([veja aqui](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)), é recomendável que construa seus `FORMS` usando o [Form Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open), pq isso vai criar um campo do tipo *hidden* que vai recuperar esse *hash* automaticamente pra vc cada vez que o `FORM` é recarregado (tb dá pra criar esse campo manualmente em cada `FORM`).

**2. Como funciona para requests sem submissão de formulários?**

Primeiro você precisa definir as configurações básicas no seu *application/config/config.php*. Eu fiz algo assim:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'ci_adminlte_csrf';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array(
    'controllerName/methodName'
);
```

Tá vendo a variável `$config['csrf_token_name']`? Esse vai ser o nome da variável no sistema, ou seja, `ci_adminlte_csrf`. Sabendo disso, saiba também de outra coisa: o `CodeIgniter` tem 2 métodos nativos pra recuperar o nome e o valor desse *token/hash*:
`get_csrf_token_name()` e `get_csrf_hash()` ([veja aqui](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)):

> If you use the form helper, then form_open() will automatically insert
>   a hidden csrf field in your forms. If not, then you can use
>   get_csrf_token_name() and get_csrf_hash()

Ou seja, pra recuperar o nome: `$name = $this->security->get_csrf_token_name()`, e pra recuperar o valor atual: `$hash = $this->security->get_csrf_hash()`.

O segredo das requisições sem `FORM`: Você tem que carregar o valor atual do hash para o navegador. `PHP` acontece no *backend*, então, toda vez que o valor do *hash* é atualizado, o navegador não sabe a menos que vc diga a ele. Eu uso uma variável `JavaScript` que recupera o valor atual pra mim.

Pra pegar o valor atual no `PHP`, uso um *method* em qualquer *controller*:

```
/**
 * Recupera o hash CSRF
 * @return string Valor do hash armazenado na memória
 */
function get_csrf_hash(){
    echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();
}
```

Usando o código: `echo $ci->security->get_csrf_token_name()."='".$ci->security->get_csrf_hash()."';\n";`. você pode criar algo assim: `ci_adminlte_csrf='909a7d6f8450a7a0d13db960184d050b';`. Eu coloquei isso num *helper* e fiz isso aqui:

```
<!--Variaveis globais-->
<script type='text/javascript'>
ci_adminlte_csrf='909a7d6f8450a7a0d13db960184d050b';
function get_csrf_hash(){
    $.get("controller/get_csrf_hash",
        function (resp) {
            ci_adminlte_csrf = resp;
            $("input[name*='ci_adminlte_csrf']").val(resp);
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

A cada *request* sem `FORM` chame a *function* `JavaScript` `get_csrf_hash()` para recarregar tanto o valor da variável quanto do `input` de nome `ci_adminlte_csrf`.

> Observação: O *config.php* da aplicação tem as variáveis `$config['cookie_prefix']` e `$config['csrf_cookie_name']` que servem para criar um cookie que instancia o valor do *token/hash* csrf. Assim, se vc precisar, pode apenas fazer o `JavaScript` recuperar o valor desse cookie que já é gravado automaticamente pela aplicação. Procure na lista de cookies do navegador.

**3. Em que parte do request fica alojado o token do hash-protection?**

Depende. Nos *requests* com `FORM` tem um campo *hidden* que carrega o valor do *hash*. Se vc não estiver construindo os `FORMS` com o [Form Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open) vai precisar criar esse campo dentro do `FORM`, e a *function* `JavaScript` `get_csrf_hash()` vai te ajudar.

Nas requisições sem `FORM` isso está descrito na resposta à pergunta 2, acima. Leia com atenção que vc vai entender onde fica armazenado e como recuperar nome e valor do *token/hash*, e a *function* `JavaScript` `get_csrf_hash()` vai te ajudar de novo.

É isso.